Anime Identification: I Thought the Title Was "Odin: A Space Odyssey"
This one may be impossible, since my memories are so hazy. When I was a child (this must have been between 1992 and 1995 or so) I was walking through an electronics store in the US, and a bank of televisions was showing an anime featuring a woman with long (waist-length or so) white hair dancing, waltz-like, with a man in a grand room on a space ship. I think that the man was wearing a military-style uniform, but that's pretty hazy.
But, years later (definitely no later than 1999), I caught what I thought was the same movie on the SciFi channel's Saturday Anime Theater programming block. I only caught the very end of it, but everything looked right. The channel guide said the movie was Odin: Space Odyssey, or so I thought. Google suggests that no such anime exists, and so I almost certainly am not getting the title right.
The anime was in color, and my memories of the art style suggest a mid-to-late-80s production and probably not any more recent than 1991. Being shown on the store TVs suggests that this was broadcast on television, and I suspect it is a feature-length movie or OVA.
So, based on my incredibly vague description, my maybe-almost-right recollection of the title, and the timing, does this sound to anyone like a specific anime?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin:_Photon_Sailer_Starlight

@aryxus That looks really, really right! And fast, too. Unfortunately I'm having trouble finding a way to watch it to confirm (that dancing scene will make it or break it for me). If you post as an answer, I'll make sure to accept yours if and when I can verify.

Also, it could be Odin: Photon Sailer Starlight. 
And I think this one is what you need. 


You should also explain why you think this is the movie. You should write some plot details which match with the description of OP.

Odin: Koushi Hansen Starlight
also much better site for threads like these
Made in 1985 so it fits the time and has white-haired girl on the cover.
EDIT: can't add a comment, and don't know the linking policy here, but you have it at nyaa

Could you explain why you believe this anime matches the question?

Because it's the only entry with Odin in name on MAL and has white-haired girl on the cover.

It is probably this one, you should just elaborate on your answer. Can't upvote such a poor answer.

Regarding your edit, I don't believe linking to pirated material is allowed on SE. But if the OP wants to look for it on NyaaTorrents, we can't really stop them.

I think you are talking about "Mission Odyssey". It's animated series about the adventures of the ancient Greek hero Odysseus.
[

Thanks for the reply, but this is definitely not it.
